# Draw custom Slider with ActionScript

Tags: flash, actionscript, adobe

Could I make my own Slider descendant (extends Slider) with thumb and scale drawn by ActionScript only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're working with the Flash compoments(fl.controls.Slider) your two questions are sort of mutually exclusive.

> Could I make my own Slider descendant (extends Slider)

Yes, you can !

> drawn by ActionScript only?

Not as much. The reason for that is that Flash components use actual library assets for it's skins, so they aren't 100% code and you would extends a class, your subclass will have a dependency on these assets. Notice that you need the components in the library, otherwise the code won't work ?

You can still write your own Slider class from scratch and implement you're own drawing routine. If still you want to extend a pre-written Slider class and deal with actionscript only, you need a code only based component. There are plenty out there, like [MinimalComponents](http://www.minimalcomps.com/).

HTH